# Can I use onClick() in an embedded SVG to call JavaScript functions in another file?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've got an SVG embedded into my **index.html**, like so...

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="map-container">
    <object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data="media/images/map.svg"></object>
</div>
```

And inside the **map.svg**, an onClick to call a function on one of my paths...

```
<path onclick="testFunction()" d="..." class="...">
```

Which relates to a function in my **map.js** file, linked in my HTML body...

```
function testFunction () {
    alert("Works!");
}
```

Clicking on the path doesn't do anything however - nothing happens. Just curious if I'm doing something wrong or if this actually isn't possible.

Comment: check your console.log error. And also check the path of `map.js` file

Comment: I've been monitoring console.log, nothing's appearing. And my map.js is accurate - I've been using it to drive other functions outside of my SVG just fine until now.